# Blob insert/update in jooq

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven, jooq-codegen, jooq-sbt-plugin

Getting "error occurred during batching: ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended.

I'm trying to update/insert byte array in Oracle BLOB column using jooq syntax as follows:-

```java
Map<Field<Object>, Object> fieldValueMap = new HashMap<>();
fieldValueMap.put(field("BLOB_COLUMN"), "test".getBytes());

Query = DSLContext.update(table(tablename)).set(fieldValueMap).where(condition)
```

Formed query for blob column as follows:-

```sql
Update tablename set BLOB_COLUMN = X'74657374' where condition.
```

Please help with the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

`X'74657374'` is the default rendering of `bytes[]` inline literals for unknown dialects, as well as a few known dialects, including e.g. H2, HSQLDB, MariaDB, MySQL, SQLite. If you had used the `SQLDialect.ORACLE` dialect, then you'd have gotten something like `hextoraw('74657374')` as generated SQL, which wouldn't produce the error you've seen.

But you probably don't want to get inline literals anyway. This probably happened because you either:

- [Used static statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/statement-type/)
- [Explicitly used inline literals](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/)

Comment: Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No  Enum Constant org.jooq.SQLDialect.ORACLE while setting dialect in default configuration. I'm using following jooq versions. Spring-boot-starter-jooq --> 2.5.12, jooq,jooq-meta,jooq-codegen--> 3.10.5

Comment: @SantoshVadje: You have to override Spring Boot's default jOOQ dependency, which is the jOOQ Open Source Edition, in order to use the commercial distributions. See: https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-use-jooqs-commercial-distributions-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Is there any way to achieve above implementation with open source edition?

Comment: @SantoshVadje: The jOOQ Open Source Edition does not support Oracle database